# org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: "kafka:29092"

Tags: spring, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to get a kafka producer to produce messages inside a docker-compose stack. When I run the producer on localhost with env variables that point to the forwarded port to the kafka container it sends successfully. When I containerize the producer application it gets the values from environment correctly, but it still throws

```
ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: "kafka:29092"
```

I have tried to follow the [confluent example](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.3.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml) and the [spring example](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/kafka-docker-setup) for setting up zookeeper and kafka in compose. here's what I have

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

networks:
  integrations:
    ipam:
      driver: default

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "yes"
      ZOO_ADMINSERVER_ENABLED: "true"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "nc", "-zv", "127.0.0.1", "2181" ]
      interval: 120s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    networks:
      integrations:

  
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092 ,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "nc", "-zv", "127.0.0.1", "9092" ]
      interval: 120s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      integrations:

  producer:
    hostname: producer
    build:
      context: https://github.com/bry-git/SampleKafkaProducer.git#main
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVER="kafka:29092"
      - KAFKA_TOPIC="primary"
    command: ["gradle", "bootRun"]
    networks:
      integrations:
```

When I run the kafka producer spring application from localhost outside of docker it connects to the broker as expected with this run config
[run config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2l9X.png)

this is my config for spring

```
# application.yml

server:
  port: 8088
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${BOOTSTRAP_SERVER}
    topic:
      name: ${KAFKA_TOPIC}
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

this is my DockerFile

```
FROM gradle:jdk11
COPY . /SampleKafkaProducer
WORKDIR /SampleKafkaProducer

ARG BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
ENV BOOTSTRAP_SERVER=${BOOTSTRAP_SERVER}
ARG KAFKA_TOPIC
ENV KAFKA_TOPIC=${KAFKA_TOPIC}

EXPOSE 8088
```

I know i have successfully gotten those values to the producer because when I get the docker logs i see kafka printing its config from inside the container when the whole stack is up.

```
# output from integration_producer_1

2023-01-31 09:04:30.001  INFO 208 --- [   scheduling-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
producer_1   |  acks = -1
producer_1   |  batch.size = 16384
producer_1   |  bootstrap.servers = ["kafka:29092"]
producer_1   |  buffer.memory = 33554432
producer_1   |  client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
producer_1   |  client.id = producer-121
producer_1   |  compression.type = none
producer_1   |  connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
producer_1   |  delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
...
producer_1   |  security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
producer_1   |  security.providers = null
producer_1   |  send.buffer.bytes = 131072
```

I have connected successfully with [offset explorer](https://offsetexplorer.com/download.html) and have exec'd into the producer container when it is running and connected to the other containers by the docker network hostname

```
root@producer:/SampleKafkaProducer# hostname
producer
root@producer:/SampleKafkaProducer# nc -zv kafka 9092
Connection to kafka (192.168.80.3) 9092 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
root@producer:/SampleKafkaProducer# nc -zv kafka 29092
Connection to kafka (192.168.80.3) 29092 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
root@producer:/SampleKafkaProducer# nc -zv zookeeper 2181
Connection to zookeeper (192.168.80.2) 2181 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
root@producer:/SampleKafkaProducer#
```

I have tried swapping `PLAINTEXT` and `PLAINTEXT_HOST` as well as their port mappings for each with every combination in my compose file. i have no clue why this doesn't work. I figured it some sort of allowed domain that works when external and i target localhost from intelliJ.
I have also tried assigning IPV4 addresses to each container via the network block in compose.

Comment: Your config seems fine, especially if it works outside of Docker. Unrelated to the error, but `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` is deprecated property. Remove it. Also, you really don't need ARG/ENV pairs in your Dockerfile. They're not even set in your Compose file (via build.args)

Comment: By the way. Remove the Dockerfile. Just use `./gradlew bootBuildImage` in the project directory

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```yaml
producer:
    <snip>
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVER="kafka:29092"
      - KAFKA_TOPIC="primary"
```

To:

```yaml
producer:
    <snip>
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVER: kafka:29092
      KAFKA_TOPIC: primary
```

You are passing `"kafka:29092"` now, instead of `kafka:29092`